# Bootstrap grid not working in small screen size

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, bootstrap-4

I want to display two columns display for all screen sizes and the code does not working in small screen size. I use bootstrap grid system and I don't know why it is not working as I excepted.

```html
<div class="app-content content container-fluid">
    <div class="content-wrapper">
        <div class="content-header row">
        </div>
        <div class="content-body"><!-- stats -->
            <div class="row match-height">
                <div class="col-xl-6 col-lg-6">
                    <div class="card">
                        <div class="card-header">  
                        </div>
                        <div class="card-body">
                            <div class="card-block">
                                <div class="row">
                                    <div class="col-lg-6 col-sm-6 col-md-6 col-6">
                                        <a href="#">Air Tempeature</a>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="col-lg-6 col-sm-6  col-md-6 col-6">
                                        <a href="#?id=<?php echo $id; ?>">Soil Temperature</a>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="row">
                                    <div class="col-lg-6 col-sm-6 col-md-6 col-6">
                                        <a href="#">Air Tempeature</a>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="col-lg-6 col-sm-6  col-md-6 col-6">
                                        <a href="#">Soil Temperature</a>    
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="row">
                                    <div class="col-lg-6 col-sm-6 col-md-6 col-6">
                                        <a href="#">Air Tempeature</a>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="col-lg-6 col-sm-6  col-md-6 col-6">
                                        <a href="#">Soil Temperature</a>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Have you followed the setup guide, https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.3/getting-started/introduction/? Without the viewport meta tag, the responsive styles will not be applied.

Comment: Meta tag and other link tags are already inserted. I did not add them in this code sample. Medium screen size and large screen size are okay, problem is in small screen size.

Comment: working fine no any changes here,  https://jsfiddle.net/lalji1051/uj4hzy93/

Comment: Okay, I fixed your indenting to make it more obvious where the nesting is. Where are you expecting to see columns?

Comment: Working fine in jsfiddle.net. I think it was because of other library files and thanks for all of your help.